# Will eddy current pendulum show deflection?

Tags: electromagnetism

Does the aluminium plate deflect due to its repulsion with the magnet?
I thought it would deflect as in the case of 'jumping aluminium ring', however from the [YouTube demostration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MglUIiBy2lQ) of this experiment, I cannot observe the deflection. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In the aluminium ring, there is an induced $current$ which induces an opposite field.

In the plate however, there is no predefined path for the current to take so it creates eddy currents which usually don't create magnetic fields nearly as strong as in a ring.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If if a ring is used instead of the pendulum, then deflection could be observed?

Comment: Yes. The reasoning would then be similar to the 'jumping' ring